# FileProvider throws exception on GetUriForFile

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

I followed the example code on the [android developer reference on FileProviders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) but it won't work.

I have setup the path `files/exports/` in the file provider definition in my Manifest and the referenced files does exist at that path.

In my Manifest:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.company.app.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

And in `xml/file_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="exports" path="exports/"/>
</paths>
```

Then I try to get the content-uri with the following code:

```
Java.IO.File exportFile = 
    new Java.IO.File ("/data/data/com.company.app/files/exports/file.pdf"); 
Android.Net.Uri exportUri = 
    Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile (this, "com.company.app.fileprovider", exportFile);
```

However I get this error:

```
Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.2-branch/4b53fbd0/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1160 
  at Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Android.Content.Context context, System.String authority, Java.IO.File file) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at com.company.App.ImageAndSubtitle.cloudStorageDidDownloadFile (System.Object sender, com.company.App.CloudStorageEventArgs args) [0x001f7] in /app_path/Screens/ImageAndSubtitle.cs:187 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:243)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:217)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:130)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update**

From the Android source code I could hunt that down so far as I now know that this command in `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:243)` will fail and return `null`:

```
final ProviderInfo info = context.getPackageManager().resolveContentProvider(authority, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

But I have no idea why...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I finally found good example code on how to create ContentProviders and FileProviders on https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider

The actual error in my code was that in the Manifest file I had the `provider` tag outside of the `application` tag, but it must be inside.
The Manifest must look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.company.app">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />

<permission
    android:name="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ"
    android:description="@string/perm_read"
    android:label="@string/perm_read_label"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ"/>

<application android:label="MyApp">

    <provider 
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
    android:authorities="com.company.app.fileprovider" 
    android:exported="false" 
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:readPermission="com.company.app.fileprovider.READ">
                <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: @ codingFriend1 i too have the same error can u plz help me posted a question in stackoverflow here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398255/how-to-merge-two-modules-in-android-studio

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. It was a silly mistake. Sometimes my brain behaves weirdly, I see something while I do something else..

Comment: It happened to me using cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing after changing the name of the application in cordova's config.xml. I had to remove and reinstall the plugin to make it work

Comment: this is gold. I haven't noticed it anywhere, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: saved my day. Also `<root-path name="root" path="." />` in `file_paths.xml` was required for me

Comment: This is a partial answer. Please complete it by adding Java side code (which you write to interact with this XML from your Activity or Fragment).

Comment: @Manoj That could be a duplicate question. This is discouraged at SOW.

Answer (score 10):

In trying to set up a FileProvider for getting a PDF file that is on the device and being able to email it out, I ran into this exception as well.  Reading the different answers out there - it seems a bit complicated to get the FileProvider set up correctly by hand *(at least this first time around)*.

Finally what worked for me was to copy the components from this example into an empty new project:
https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/tree/master/PdfShare

Once I see it working in the standalone, then I'm able to bring in the changes to my actual project.

Specifically, here are the files to replicate:

**1. AndroidManifest.xml** - *where all the tricky FileProvider config is*

- https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/blob/master/PdfShare/AndroidManifest.xml

**2. file_paths.xml** - *This is a small but important component. Looking on SO there are a variety of answers for what to put there, however only from this project did the set up work for me*

- https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/blob/master/PdfShare/res/xml/file_paths.xml

**3. MainActivity.java** - *the corresponding Java setup to work with what's configured in the manifest; and of course don't forget the associated layout file*

- https://github.com/IanDarwin/Android-Cookbook-Examples/blob/master/PdfShare/src/main/java/com/example/pdfshare/MainActivity.java

Comment: I also ran into a bunch of answers out there but this compilation was the closest set I found. I had to make some minor adjustments to adapt it for Xamarin.Android. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred in my case because I had passed an incorrect package name to the second parameter of `GetUriForFile`. I used `BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME` which resolved to *android.support.multidex* which is incorrect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17332725)

Comment: its just another mistake to get same exception

Comment: for example first time i use BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME that was "android.support.multidex" by default

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this helped me. My fault, I changed my package name mid way through development and forgot to also go back and update the manifest file. AHHH!!!!!!