# Android - how to determine calling app's package name

Tags: android

I have been facing this issue recently where I can't find a way to get calling application's package name in my activity.

1. If the calling app used `startActivityForResult`, then its fine, and I can rely on `Activity.getCallingPackage()` to get the caller's package name
2. But when a caller uses `startActivity()` the above method will return null. Also, in this case if I just use `getPackageManager().getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid())`, then it gives me the package name of the current app.

Can anyone suggest a reliable way to get the package name of the calling app in my activity ?

Comment: If this is a follow-on to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial), I stand by [my recommendation there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467912/115145), of trying to avoid all of this by including `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare No no .. I was trying a different test, wherein I was trying to get an intent from a browser, and in the app wanted to know which package invoked the activity, but couldn't get it. So I decided to ask this question. I will follow your recommendation for URI permissions ! :)