# Get package name of third-party application from main application

Tags: android, package

I've got two applications, one's launching the other one.

I'm trying to get the package name of the first application from the second. How can I get it ?

In advance, thanks.

Comment: seems like a duplicate but cant find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are someways to get the packagename of the calling application, But it depends on how you're starting it. If you're using **startActivity**, then you should put your packagename as a string in the **Intent.putExtra**.
If you're using **startActivityForResult()**, then there are **Activity.getCallingPackage() and getCallingActivity().getPackageName();**.

Also, you can refer to this question :
[Android - how to determine calling app's package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468765/android-how-to-determine-calling-apps-package-name)

Answer (score 0):

use `getCallingActivity().getPackageName();` to get package name of calling activity.