# Camera crashes, when trying to save fileI

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-fileprovider, android-mvp

I'm stucked. Here is my methods, that get picture from camera, and save them:

```
> > @Override
>     public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
>         String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
>         String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
>         File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
>         File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
>         model.currentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
>         return imageFile;
>     }

@Override
public Intent getCameraPictureIntent(PackageManager packageManager) {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (pictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        try {
            model.userPicFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Can't create file!");
        }
        if (model.userPicFile != null) {
            model.userPicFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    "com.internship.droidz.talkin.fileprovider",
                    model.userPicFile);
            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, model.userPicFileUri);
        }
    }
    return pictureIntent;
}
```

I'm creating tempfile, then get uri, set it to intent. And then startActivity for result. When i take photo and submit it, app crashes. Logcat says nothing.

here is stored file and uri:

```
    public class RegistrationModel implements RegistrationContract.RegistrationModel {

    String currentPhotoPath;
    Uri userPicFileUri;
    File userPicFile;
}
```

Here is permissions in Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
```

Compiling for API 19+

That is Log.i says:

```
01-30 14:39:18.721 3265-3265/com.android.camera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.android.camera, PID: 3265
                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{52a0a5b0 3265:com.android.camera/u0a36} (pid=3265, uid=10036) that is not exported from uid 10058
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2848)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4399)
                                                                  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2208)
                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:906)
                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
                                                                  at com.android.camera.Camera.doAttach(Camera.java:1385)
                                                                  at com.android.camera.Camera.onReviewDoneClicked(Camera.java:1362)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818) 
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Permissions problems maybe? What android version are you compiling for?

Comment: "Logcat says nothing."  I'm guessing your app restarts and the android studio logcat view is showing you only logging of the latest running instance, try changing logcat to "No Filter" to see the error. or change `Log.i(TAG, "Can't create file!");` to `Log.e(TAG, "Can't create file!", e);`

Comment: Thanks to all! I resolved this problem, using answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all! I resolved this problem, using answer [Android - file provider - permission denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial)

```
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```