# Android Blank screen on PDF

Tags: android

In My App, I have given all permissions like storage, contact etc to app (Given run time permission for marshmallow and above version), but still app shows black screen for some mobile phone.

`Permission Denial: opening provider`

> android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{bd58bf1
>   15489:com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer/u0a213} (pid=15489, uid=10213)

**That is not exported from uid 10227.**

//Code

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
pdfFile);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedIntentActivities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(objIntent,
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolvedIntentInfo : resolvedIntentActivities) {
            String packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            context.grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        objIntent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "application/pdf");
        context.startActivity(objIntent);
    }else{
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(objIntent);
    }`
```

[Screen]
    [image]

Comment: You haven't shown any code, just an error and a blank screen.

Comment: You appear to be trying to start a third-party PDF viewer, using a `Uri` from `FileProvider`. Given that, you appear to have failed to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, and so that PDF viewer has no rights to access your content. But, as David points out, this is guesswork -- please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Code added, Please let me know the wrong thing in code

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually there might be some issue with accessing the FILE URI as it doesnt have the write read uri permission while raising the intent.

check the following thread.. [Android - file provider - permission denial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial)
hope you will get some idea.

Also post the code here to understand more.

Comment: I have given
objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
  setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
  addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
}

val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open PDF with...")
startActivity(chooserIntent)
```