# How to get Glide to display a local photo with a URI

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am trying to get Glide to display a local jpeg file in an ImageView.

I have created this simple example that shows my problem. Normally, I obtain the URI programatically, but for this example I am just using the hard coded uri string from one of the files I am trying to display. When I run it, the ImageView is empty.

```
package com.example.g1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("content://org.chromium.arc.file_system.fileprovider/download/assets/images/DSC01062.JPG")
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="356dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this image at your local storage?

Comment: Please visit this then enable logcat when loading this image. If you still cannot solve it, just post logcat here.
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html

Comment: The file IS local,

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial

Comment: I  saw that post, but I don't know how it applies to my situation. If I plug in the code that resolved the issue, I dont know what to use to set the value of the "intent" variable.