# App Crashes on Redmi Devices while opening camera

Tags: android, android-camera, redmi-device

Opening camera crashes the app on Redmi Devices(android 10 and above ) works fine in other company devices. Please find the error log below.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{eed3e70 21469:com.android.camera/u0a72} (pid=21469, uid=10072) that is not exported from UID 10315
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:5283)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6723)
    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2749)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:2133)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1520)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1242)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1218)
    at com.android.camera.module.Camera2Module.doAttach(Camera2Module.java:8)
    at com.android.camera.module.Camera2Module.onReviewDoneClicked(Camera2Module.java:1)
    at com.android.camera.fragment.FragmentBottomIntentDone.onClick(FragmentBottomIntentDone.java:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7161)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:818)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27683)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:7199)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:7542)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2179)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2802)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
```

Comment: Where is your crash log?

Comment: @Piyush I have updated my description

Comment: You need to use register _FileProvider_ in your manifest file and give a proper path by creating _xml_ folder in _res_ folder.

Comment: You can check [this](https://ali-dev.medium.com/open-a-file-in-another-app-with-android-fileprovider-for-android-7-42c9abb198c1)

Comment: @Piyush It  is already done and it is working fine on other device the problem is only with Redmi device

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial)?

Comment: @Piyush I am following those steps .

Comment: Which MI device do you have?

Comment: Also have you added _android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"_ in manifest file?