# How to call openInputStream not happen SecurityException

Tags: android

I try context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) but happen "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider ... requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()"
uri is ShareCompat#stream.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467696/android-file-provider-permission-denial) should help you.

Comment: @grabarz121 Should I need call grantUriPermission?