# Files doesnt shows its conent if they called from MyApp to view in other App

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have next situation.
I get file from bytesArray, build file from it, and wonna view this file from other application.

1. File builds correctly (I can see that from file system)
2. I can open that file through file system and it openes correctly.
3. If I try to view this file from my app through other app I get some unexpected cases.

For example:
I use image/jpg, and wonna view it through google photo, and app showes me  black screen, and if i try to use some app action (image info), app crashes.

```
File file, outputFile = null;
String fileName;
if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
   .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
     file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".MyApp/Files/");
     if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
     }
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
     fileName = "report_" + sdf.format(new Date());
     outputFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + finalExtention);
}
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
fileOutputStream.close();
Intent intent = new Intent();
String mime = getMimeType(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
String filePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), mime);
Intent intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an application to open with:");
startActivity(intentChooser);
```

getMimeType return String like "image/jpeg" 
finalExtension gets from json (for this case ".jpg")

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What I see from MyApp: 
[From MyApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grbxh.jpg)

What I see from File System: [From File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdf4R.jpg)

Searching for help, guys. No idea what I'm doing wrong with intents. 
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

If someone looking for working example, here some code changes you need to do:

```
Uri fileUri = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.myapp.packadge.fileprovider", outputFile);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mime);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
      ....

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myApp.packadge.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

filepath.xml

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="internalStorage/outputDir/" name="reports" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `bytes` you write to the file are in a correct jpg format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer versions of Android it has been changed. Now you have to define provider in your manifest file to let another appliactions access your files: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html.

It has been also answered on stackoverflow: [How to use support FileProvider for sharing content to other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps)

Comment: Thanks, its work's for me. Already apply some changes and its works!