# Unable to pick image from Google Photos app

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, google-photos

I'm using the following code (in Kotlin) to select an image from the Google Photos app on my Samsung tablet.

```
val intent =  Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.type = "image/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PHOTOS_IMAGE)
```

I've also tried

```
Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
```

On running this code I get a slideout that allows me to select the Photos app, from which I can then select a photo.  However, once I select the photo, the app does not return the image to my app as it does with the camera and gallery.  It instead returns to the slideout. When I hit the back button to close the slideout, onActivityResult is called with RESULT_CANCELED and 0 data.

I am able to retrieve photos from the Gallery and the camera without issue so I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Maybe a permission or something else in the Manifest?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957859/pick-from-google-photos-provider-with-action-get-content-or-open-document/64291034#64291034) in case that you start your intent from an activity with `singleInstance` launch mode. that was solve the same issue that you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was not connected to the network so Google Photos was unable to retrieve the selected image.  See my response to @adityakamble49.

Answer (score 0):

Let try like this,

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        }
```

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT doesn't work.  In this case, the app skips the slideout entirely (so no option to select Photos or any other app) and goes right to a screen of gallery photos.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ACTION_GET_CONTENT** Intent Action - `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

Call following `selectImage()` method to start pick image Intent, which will display all apps available to select image from

```
private val RC_SELECT_IMGAE = 101

private fun selectImage() {
    val selectImageIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media
            .EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(selectImageIntent, RC_SELECT_IMGAE)
}
```

Then handle callback by overriding `onActivityResult()` method in **Activity**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        RC_SELECT_IMGAE -> {
            if (data != null) {
                val uri = data.data
                displaySelectedImage(getBitmapFromUri(uri))
            }
        }
        else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Finally update the image view with bitmap as below

```
private fun getBitmapFromUri(uri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
    val fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor
    val image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor)
    parcelFileDescriptor.close()
    return image
}

private fun displaySelectedImage(imageBitmap: Bitmap) {
    iv_selected_image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
}
```

Find Working Image Picker Example here - [ImagePickerExample](https://github.com/adityakamble49/image-picker-example)

You may want to add `FileProvider` in case it gives any kind of URI Exception

- [Android Documentation - Setup Sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)
- [Setup File Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps)

Comment: ACTION_PICK does not work.  It allows me to pick from the gallery only,  not the google photos app.  This is one of the many solutions I had already tried during my search before posting on SO.

Comment: I should mention that if I include intent.type = "image/*" in that ACTION_PICK request, I can select a photo from google photos but it returns RESULT_CANCELED to onActivityResult instead of the image.

Comment: @jilbot Its working on my side using same code as mentioned above. I have quickly created sample app for picking images. Checkout over here - https://github.com/adityakamble49/image-picker-example

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide that!   In the meantime I have discovered that the problem was that my device was not connected to the network.  I turned on WiFi and am now able to get a photo, which has to be downloaded from the cloud.  I erroneously expected that my google photos would be stored on the device, but it appears they are in the cloud only.   So I have to learn more about the photos app, including if and when it stores my photos on the device.  In any case, ACTION_PICK and ACTION_GET_CONTENT now work as expected.

Comment: @jilbot Glad to help.You can surely upvote and approve the answer to thank. :)
I have updated the post and example with ACTION_GET_CONTENT action. Now its working with offline as well as online files.

Comment: Deserves an upvote and I tried to do it earlier but I don't have enough reputation points :-(

Comment: @jilbot. No issue. You can accept the answer though :)

Comment: I wasn't sure people would see the solution (need to connect to network) all the way down in the comments.  I posted it as the answer and accepted it, referring to your helpful answer as well.  If/when I get enough rep, I'll add the upvote.