# Pick from Google Photos provider with ACTION_GET_CONTENT or OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, google-photos, document-provider

I have no clue at why this happens, but I am not able to pick images from the Google Photos provider. Testing on API 27.

### With ACTION_GET_CONTENT

If I use:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "image/*"
```

- I can see Google Photos among the provider
- I can browse to some picture and select it
- Then I am directed back to the providers list (not to my app), as if the provider had crashed in a try-catch

When I open the Photos provider and navigate through folders I see lots of these:

```
2019-03-02 12:04:15.164 17641-13395/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(120) failed with errno -22
2019-03-02 12:04:22.528 13217-13217/? E/ResourceType: Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010586
2019-03-02 12:04:22.535 13217-13217/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f020366, entry index(870) is beyond type entryCount(468)
```

When I click on the picture, I see these:

```
2019-03-02 12:04:34.150 13217-13217/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f02036c, entry index(876) is beyond type entryCount(468)
2019-03-02 12:04:34.151 13217-13217/? W/ResourceType: For resource 0x7f02036c, entry index(876) is beyond type entryCount(468)
2019-03-02 12:04:34.229 2907-16891/? W/MediaExtractor: FAILED to autodetect media content.
2019-03-02 12:04:34.569 10839-10839/? W/ResourceType: ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 468, previously 1330
```

### With ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

In this case I don't even see Google Photos in the providers drawer.

### Question

How can I solve this, preferably with ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: Try with `ACTION_PICK`

Comment: Thanks but I need to use one of these two and I would like to know why it's not working.

Comment: @natario which device you are using?!

Comment: @Rahul Nexus 5X , api 27

Comment: @natario  Are you testing it on emulator? or the real device

Comment: @natario Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909105/4079010)

Comment: It is a real device, a Nexus 5X.

Comment: May be its a bug. But i have tested it on Nexus 5X API 27 emulator. which is same as your device. And the code is also working fine here. P.S. Check for updates

Comment: @natario check my updated answer. and let me know if you need explanation.

Comment: @Rahul onActivityResult is never called because the flow doesn't go back to my app, it stays in the chooser as I have said.

Comment: @natario i wonder what makes it not working for you on real device but on emulator.

Comment: @RahulKhurana I've checked this code on the phone with the same model as yours and it work's without any problem. you steel have this problem.

Comment: @Alishatergholi OP is facing this problem. I'm just trying to resolve it anyway

Comment: @RahulKhurana please check my code, It work's well on Nexus 5X.

Comment: @Alishatergholi Ok. I will

Comment: I understand that it works for you, but it still doesn't for me.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 2**

I think i found the solution of the problem. It is mentioned in the [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html) that accessing a shared file will give you the **URI**.

> The server app sends the file's content URI back to the client app in an Intent. This Intent is passed to the client app in its override of onActivityResult(). Once the client app has the file's content URI, it can access the file by getting its FileDescriptor.

Below is the updated code i am using inside **onActivityResult**. Make sure to call the **super** method of onActivityResult at last.

> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

Working code

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
data?.data?.let {
    util._log(TAG, it.toString())
}
if (data!!.data != null && data.data != null) {
    try {

        val stream = if (data.data!!.toString().contains("com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider")) {
            val ff = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(data.data!!, "r")
            FileInputStream(ff?.fileDescriptor)
        } else {
            contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
        }
        val createFile = createImageFile()
        util.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, createFile)
        selectedImagePath = createFile.absolutePath

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        util._log(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e))
    }
}
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

**EDIT**

Also check this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909105/4079010)

**Original**

I am using it on Android **oreo 8.1.0(API 27)** on my Redmi 6 pro phone and it is working fine.

You haven't posted the **onActivityResult** method may be this is where you need to do some modifications. I have tried it both

Below is my code snippet

```
val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
pickIntent.type = "image/*"
pickIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
pickIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

startActivityForResult(pickIntent, SELECT_PICTURE)
```

and in **onActivityResult** i am parsing it like this

```
if (data!!.data != null && data.data != null) {
    try {
        //                    CommonUtilities._Log(TAG, "Data Type " + data.getType());
        if (!isFinishing) {
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data!!)
            val createFile = createImageFile()
            copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream!!, createFile)
            //                        CommonUtilities._Log(TAG, "File Path " + createFile.getAbsolutePath());
            selectedImagePath = createFile.absolutePath
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        util._log(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e))
    }
}
```

**Method to create a new file**

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "yesqueen_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
}
```

**Method to read from inputstream**

```
fun copyInputStreamToFile(`in`: InputStream, file: File) {
    var out: OutputStream? = null
    try {
        out = FileOutputStream(file)
        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int = 0
        while (`in`.read(buf).apply { len = this } > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len)
        }

        /*while (`in`.read(buf).let {
                    len = it
                    true
                }) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len)
        }*/
        /* while ((len = `in`.read(buf)) > 0) {
             out.write(buf, 0, len)
         }*/
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            out?.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        try {
            `in`.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but onActivityResult is never called because the device does not even go back to my app. It goes back to the system image chooser (the one with the drawer). So: app -> system chooser -> select Google Photos -> pick a picture -> back to chooser.

Comment: Had you given it a try as in my answer??

Comment: @natario i have also attached a GIF that shows it is working :)

Comment: You have used the same 3 lines that are in my question - ACTION_GET_CONTENT, CATEGORY_OPENABLE and "image/*", so yes I have tried. I also think these are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it with this code.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "image/*"
startActivityForResult(intent,100)
```

and for result

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        100 -> {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val bitmap = generateBitmap(this,data!!.data)
                //TODO show bitmap to your View
                showPicture(bitmap!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`generateBitmap(context,uri)` method in Kotlin

```
fun generateBitmap(context: Context, uri: Uri): Bitmap? {
    var filePath = ""
    var cursor: Cursor?
    var columnIndex = 0
    try {
        val column = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val sel = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?")
        if (uri.toString().startsWith("content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider")){
            val content = this.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) ?: return null
            val pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content)
            return pictureBitmap
        } else {
            filePath = ""
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                val wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val id = arrayOf(wholeID.split(":")[1])
                cursor = context.contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel[0], id, null)
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0])
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                }
                cursor.close()
            } else {
                val cursorLoader = CursorLoader(context, uri, column, null, null, null)
                val cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground()
                if (cursor != null) {
                    var column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                    cursor.moveToFirst()
                    filePath = cursor.getString(column_index)
                }
            }
            //TODO generate bitmap from file path
            return bitmap(filePath)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        print(e.message)
    }
    return null
}
```

for getBitmap from file path I used this method

```
 fun bitmap(path : String) : Bitmap{
    val image = File(path)
    val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.absolutePath, bmOptions)
}
```

Comment: @natario I've changed part of the answer, I hope that's solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I could not get image URI from Google Photos with a `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent. The problem was related to `launchMode` of my activity. I could not find any reference to Android documentations. but this way the problem completely solved:

I had a single activity application and my `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent was something like this:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
      type = "image/*"
}
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RESULT)
```

the problem was `singleInstance` launch mode in activity's definition in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
```

By removing the android:launchMode line the problem was solved. If your activity needs to be `singleInstance`, creating a dummy activity will be a good solution. here you can start a dummy activity for result and then do your Intent stuff inside its `onCreate` and then `setResult()` for your requested activity:

```
class ImagePickerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
            type = "image/*"
        }

        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager!!) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_RESULT)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "No Gallery APP installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            finish()
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        //here data is resulted URI from ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        //and we pass it to our MainActivy using setResult
        setResult(resultCode, data)
        finish()
    }
}
```

and here is your code in your MainActivity:

```
gallery.setOnClickListener {
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent(requireActivity(), ImagePickerActivity::class.java),
        GALLERY_RESULT
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975177/registerforactivityresult-returning-empty-list-of-results-after-choosing-to-brow

Answer (score 0):

The **ACTION_PICK** will give the option to pick the image and you can get the file path

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Image.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");

                Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
                sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                sIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent;
                if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null) {
                    // it is device with samsung file manager
                    chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Select file");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{intent});
                } else {
                    chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file");
                }
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No suitable File Manager was found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use ACTION_PICK. I need to use one of the two (get content / open document).