# registerForActivityResult returning empty list of results after choosing to browse files in other apps

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I register for an intent callback to get content via:

```
val pickPhotosFromLibrary = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) { uris: List<Uri> ->
    // Handle uris.
}
```

and call via:

```
pickPhotosFromLibrary.launch("image/*")
```

This brings up a list of "Recent images" and an option to "BROWSE FILES IN OTHER APPS". I am able to get images into the callback from the recent list, but if I go into the other apps option (specifically the Photos app), the uris list is empty after selecting and clicking "Done"

[image: Pick images browser]

I've also tried with the `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()` and the result is similar: the single returned URI works for photos chosen from the first "recent" list, but is null when selecting from "other" apps.

Comment: Seems related to `launchMode` of `singleInstance` ... switching to `singleTask` fixes the issue for me. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957859/pick-from-google-photos-provider-with-action-get-content-or-open-document

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue when launching it from ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() and trying to select an image from a different app inside the picker. I am doing it inside a bottomSheetDialogFragment which is again a child fragment