# No resources found that matches the given name Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement a file provider in *Xamarin.Forms*, and I am having an issue loading my file paths file. Whenever I attempt to build that app, I get the following error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with
>   value '@xml/file_paths')

The *file_paths.xml* file is located in the resources directory under the xml folder. Any help would greatly appreciated. Here are my relevant files:

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" package="com.mycompany.myapp" android:versionName="1" android:installLocation="internalOnly">
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/advanced" android:label="FD CANNECT" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >
    <provider 
      android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
      android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider" 
      android:exported="false" 
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data 
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
          android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="downloads" path="downloads/" />
</paths>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using CAN2LAN.Droid;
using Java.Lang;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ShareIntent))]

namespace CAN2LAN.Droid
{
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        UserDialogs.Init(this);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        Downloaded();

        Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) => {
            args.Handled = false;
        };

        this.LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public void Downloaded() {
        CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file => {
            string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last();
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
        });
    }


}

public class ShareIntent : IShareable {
    public void OpenShareIntent(string fileName) {         
        OpenFile(fileName);
    }

    public void OpenFile(string fileName) {
        string auth = "com.myapp.fileprovider";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Auth is " + auth);
        string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName.ToLower()));
        if (mimeType == null)
            mimeType = "*/*";
        Android.Net.Uri uri = null;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Created authentication and mime type");
        var file = new Java.IO.File(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File size is " + file.TotalSpace);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Froms context is " + Forms.Context);
        try {
             uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Forms.Context, auth, file);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception " + e);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("URI is "  + uri);


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Intent is created");
        // Trying to allow writing to the external app ...
        var resInfoList = Forms.Context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
        foreach (var resolveInfo in resInfoList) {
            var packageName = resolveInfo.ActivityInfo.PackageName;
            Forms.Context.GrantUriPermission(packageName, uri, ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantPrefixUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have created res info lsit");
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We are about to show the intent");
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We ahe shwoed the intent");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("We have caugth an exception " + e);
        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried but this could be the issue.
Here problem seem with your *file_paths.xml* file. You are giving name & path both are same

```
name="downloads" path="downloads/"
```

Those might be different

Either this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="external_files"/>
</paths>
```

Or

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

For more information you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps)

**Edit 1**

Check *file_paths.xml* file build action, It should be *AndroidResource*

Comment: I changed the file_paths.xml to your code and I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried restarting Visual Studio and restarting my computer.

Comment: Don't change according to me change according you. File name should be file name & path should be path   `name="share"
        path="external_files`

Comment: I set the file_paths.xml as an AndroidResource, which seemed to have solved the initial error. However, no when the app launches, I get the following exception: `Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Changing the build action to _AndroidResource_ worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the real answer to this question was mentioned by @bradykey

"Changing the build action to AndroidResource"

You can do this by right clicking the file and selecting properties. Here you can choose the build action.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your XML file is all lowercase. That fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: And why should this be a comment? It is a valid answer to why this error occurs.