# Getting IllegalArgumentException error when using aFileChooser library

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-8.0-oreo, android-download-manager

I have followed [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) library for resume uploading. When I'm uploading a resume so I'm getting below mentioned exception. I'm getting this issue in Oreo 8.0+ devices. Might be this library is not compatible for 8.0+ devices. Is there any other solution for the same?

Please help me out.

```
11-14 13:58:12.684 9676-9676/ E/FileSelectorTestActivity: File select error
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/44
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
            at com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getPath(FileUtils.java:311)
            at com.mpg.manpowerce.controllers.fragments.MPGCreateProfileUploadContentFragment.onActivityResult(MPGCreateProfileUploadContentFragment.java:296)
            at com.mpg.manpowerce.controllers.MPGHomeActivity.onActivityResult(MPGHomeActivity.java:706)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
            at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Manifest File :

This is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yourpackagename">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />

    <application
        android:name="yourpackagename.MPGUnHandledExceptionHandler"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mpg_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/mpg_app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/mpg_theme"
        android:value="@string/mpg_app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="yourpackagename.MPGSplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/mpg_app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="yourpackagename.MPGHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/mpg_app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" >
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="yourpackagename.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="share"
        path="external_files"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps

Comment: Can you please post your `provider_paths.xml` code.

Comment: @ChintanSoni I have posted xml file

Comment: @sasikumar That is fileprovider and I'm using that library so what I have to change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In `provider_paths.xml` try to add one more path as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    ...
    <external-path
        name="downloads"
        path="downloads" />
    ...
</paths>
```

And check if you're getting this erorr again.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error @Chintan Soni. Thanks

Comment: Can you please suggested me?