# How to get the path of a Bitmap to use in Uri

Tags: java, android

I am trying to share an image. To do so i need the path of the bitmap to send it in Uri.
The current line i have is deprecated and depending on the API result Null.

```
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Challengers", null);
```

What is the proper way to get the path of a Bitmap to share a Bitmap to other app using Uri?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Save your `Bitmap` to your app's internal storage, and then set up a `FileProvider` to serve it up to external apps. There's a pretty complete example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619468).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what was causing problems. I had put permissions in the Manifest but also needed to add a couple lines in onCreate

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},requestCode);
    onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},grantResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imgUrl) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code to get Image Uri,

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```