# couldn't attach file send email android 11

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I am developing an application that sends processing reports via email. When completing the processing data in the application, the user sends an email containing the processing data. However, I am facing a problem on Android 11. When attaching the report to the email, regardless of the email application, a message appears: the file could not be attached. I've been researching a little and saw that it may be related to the permission to access the internal storage of the device on devices with version of android 11. I would like me to help you send email with file attached on android 11.

My code:
Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
    tools:targetApi="n">

    <activity.....
     <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>
```

My xml:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
   <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Save file .pdf

```
val mDocProc = Document()
            val file =
                File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString() + "/" + "Relatório diário" + date + ".pdf"
                )
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete()
            }
            //pdf file path
            mFilePathDaily =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + "/" + "Relatório diário " + date + ".pdf"
```

Class send email:

```
val report = File(mFilePathDaily)
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                activity.requireContext(),
                activity.requireContext().applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                report
            )

            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
            i.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("testesdissertacao@gmail.com"))
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT)
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Segue em anexo o relatório de Benchmark")
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            //i.type = "image/png"
            activity.requireContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, null))
            progressDialog.dismiss()
```

Now the problem is that you can't find the report to attach to the email. I noticed that the report was saved inside that other folder in the emulator, and not in the root folder. I think that is why you are not finding the file to attach to the email.

[image]

[image]

Do not attach the file to the email

[image]

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://$mFilePathDaily")` You cannot use file uries since Android N/7. They will produce an FileUriExposedException. Use FileProvider.getUriForFile().

Comment: does that solve? How? @blackapps

Comment: Using FileProvider to attach and share the file for android 10 and Above version.

Comment: You can store the file at the path given by `context.externalCacheDir` and then access it easily. Else, you'll have to get separate accesses. Read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have attached the image successfully in email i will give you a code

convert your URI to file

```
 private void Share(File savepath) {
       
 if (savePath != null) {

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", savePath);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fake@fake.edu"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"On The Job");
            //Log.d("URI@!@#!#!@##!", Uri.fromFile(pic).toString() + "   " + pic.exists());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"All Detail of Email are here in message");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            i.setType("image/png");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share you on the jobing"));

        }
```

how to add provider in XML path
first, you have to create an XML resource folder then create an XML resource file
after pasting this code

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

then also add-in manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

[image: file provider in xml]

[image: decalre in manifest]

Comment: Axar, I edited the question with your suggestions in the implementation. You do not yet attach the file to the email. I suspected that I wouldn't be saving to storage. However, as seen in the question I attached the print of where it is being saved. Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @TecnologiadaNet  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri); check your uri

Comment: but I want to show only email options. SENDTO shows all options like message, bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

You and email apps won't be able to access files on Android 11. Try to use SAF instead.
[How to use support FileProvider for sharing content to other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send an email with pdf attachment using the code below. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oKbV.png) Crucial was granting READ_URI_PERMISSION and WRITE_URI_PERMISSION, using ACTION_SEND instead of ACTION_SENDTO and the Uri being linked to a pdf file in one of the standard directories such as Download or Documents. I did not need to convert Uri to File.:

```
  //obtaining the uri to the pdf report when creating it
  Uri pathToPdf = null;
  int EmailRequestCode = 200;
  ContentResolver contentresolver = getContentResolver();
  ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
  contentvalues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, pdfFileName);
  contentvalues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
  contentvalues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator +"Reports");
  pathToPdf = contentresolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentvalues);

  //... writing data to the pdf

  //getting email addresses to include in the email
  String[] mailto = listMailAddressTO.toArray(new String[2]);
  String[] mailCC = listMailAddressCC.toArray(new String[2]);

  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mailCC);
  emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "UllageReport (Pdf)");                                
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "UllageReport");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathToPdf);
  try{
      if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
          startActivityForResult(emailIntent, EmailRequestCode);
      }
  }
  catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
       Toast.makeText(UllageReportPdf.this, "No email client available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: Your catch block is useless because of your resolveActivity condition.
I suggest get rid of the if condition

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was I had to replace res/xml/file_paths.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths>
    <external-path
         name="external"
         path="." />
    <external-files-path
         name="external_files"
         path="." />
    <cache-path
         name="cache"
         path="." />
    <external-cache-path
         name="external_cache"
         path="." />
    <files-path
         name="files"
         path="." />
</paths>
```

You should use only the lines you need to make it work.

Comment: for me it works   "    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />"   but    in android 13 samsung phones first time unable to attach file,..