# Move existing Folder from external storage to internal storage API 30 Android

Tags: android

My question is not duplicate to:

[Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated in API level 29 java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java)
or

[Android 11 Scoped storage permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782648/android-11-scoped-storage-permissions)
or

[Android 11 - Accessing Files in my app Android/Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947344/android-11-accessing-files-in-my-app-android-data-folder)

Answers provided in above links doesn't solve my problem as my App already targets API level 30.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated in API level 29 java.

I made a folder in External directory when API level was below 29 and had my encrypted DB placed there. I have to upgrade to API 30 as Android has forced me to do so. Now I am unable to access my folder when I moved to API 30. How can I move that folder to a place which can be easily accessible by getExternalFilesDir()?

**I cannot access through getExternalFilesDir() or MediaStore as the file is not media file.
I cannot use Intent actions as I can't ask app user to access the folder.
Please help.**

Comment: You should then copy it to a sub folder of getExternalFilesDir.

Comment: I am unable to access my folder on external storage, hence unable to copy it.

Comment: You did not tell that in your post. Any reason? This does not match `made a folder in External directory and had my encrypted DB placed there. `

Comment: I think I drafted the question very badly.

Comment: @blackapps You have answered many such posts. Can you please support me in this?

Comment: @blackapps How can I remove the duplicate question tag as my question is not duplicate or answered anywhere else.

Comment: You should ask @Zoe ... moderator is often too soon..

Comment: But lets not wait for a moderator ... Use SAF and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select your folder.

Comment: `cannot access through ...... MediaStore as the file is not media file` That does not matter. Did you try?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: @blackapps I'm not a moderator (I do moderation, but doing moderation != [being a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306596/what-is-the-difference-between-a-moderator-and-a-privileged-user#comment250268_306598)), and with 3k rep, you should already be familiar with how reopening works rather (spoiler alert: it's not assigning blame). I'm not going to reopen because "my App already targets API level 30." isn't a reason why none of them apply. The last two I used on this one explicitly target API 30

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: @Zoe, i'm not a moderator and i do no moderation. Hope to keep it that way.

Comment: @blackapps oh trust me, I've noticed.

Comment: @blackapps ,Zoe How to move my files from public directory to `Android/Media/com.myapp` directory in android 11 like whatsapp did without asking any permission? how to get public directory path if `getExternalStorageDirectory` is now deprecated in Q?

Comment: @bdevloper If you haven't migrated your project to API 30 yet.. Build your app with API 29 and move your existing files from public directory(as public directory are accessible till API 29). We still have around one month after which Google will force us to publish app with Android 30 or above.

Comment: i did move using kotlin Utils class here [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265107/6333971)

Comment: @mobile_tech - Did you find a suitable solution to this?

Comment: @ErezAmir No. Only way was to build app and upload app on API-29 and migrate data to internal folder.

Comment: @mobile_tech Catch22 :-) - red-tape at its best