# How to solve Xamarin Forms SQLite Android 11 error?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-11

I am updating an application that works on API 29/Android Q devices but not Android 11. I understand that there are new scoped storage updates and am already receiving permissions from the user for

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My code looks something like this:

```
//the path returns /data/user/0/com.company.MyApp/files/MyAppDB.sqlite
            var Path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var asyncConn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path);
            try
            {
                await asyncConn.CreateTableAsync<SampleObject>();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                return false; 
            }
```

When executing CreateTableAsync I receive an object reference error. This is only happening with Android 11 emulators/devices.

This does not seem to be an issue with SQLite but an issue accessing the sqlite file, or writing to it at least.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#maintain-compatibility-android-10

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at that doc several times and tried implementing some of it. Are you saying to unset both flags for DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE and 
FORCE_ENABLE_SCOPED_STORAGE? Do you have a link on how to do that as I cannot find anything for Xamarin

Comment: have you tried `requestLegacyExternalStorage`?

Comment: Yes, it is set to true. Per the docs it doesn't apply to apps targeting Android 11.

Comment: Android 11 has access restrictions on internal storage, what is the version of target in your project ? If it is lower than Android 10 ,even you're trying to deploy on a Android 11 , it could be solved by enabling `requestLegacyExternalStorage` , but if the project is targeting Android 11,  only the external storage is allowed to access, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()` to get the path ,pls check https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#app-specific-external

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I am trying to target Android 11 and changed the path to getExternalFilesDirs. Here is my path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.MyApp/files/MyAppDB.sqlite` and unfortunately still getting an object reference error when running CreateTableAsync.

Comment: Try to use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` , check https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962161/8187800.