# Saving PDF in external Download directory on Android 11

Tags: android, storage, android-11, scoped-storage

In android 11 scoped storage is introduced. According to documentation to save non media file (like PDF) Storage Access framework should be use. So using Storage access framework user needs to choose location with system file picker to save non media file (PDF). But If you use whatsapp application on android 11 and try to save PDF file ,It never ask user to select location. By default it will save pdf file to external document directory.
I want to replicate same behaviour in My application. Can somebody guide me here.

Comment: 1 possibility can be what's app is still targeting api 29

Answer (score 0):

you have to visit these question of answer given by me

[couldn't attach file send email android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641751/couldnt-attach-file-send-email-android-11/66719299#66719299)

from these link, you have to get a file provider code please add these code to store your file

https://acomputerengineer.com/2018/09/06/create-pdf-and-save-to-the-sdcard-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android developers documentation they recently introduced the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
acquire this permission and you are good to go access and save any where accept system folders.

Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files