# How can i attach pdf file from my internel storage to gmail app programatically

Tags: java, android

Intent intentShareFile = new
Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {mailTo});
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(path);

```
if(fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
    intentShareFile.setType("application/pdf");
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myfile));
    

    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "SUBJECT");
    intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MESSAGE");
    intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intentShareFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
}
```

- List item

Comment: please check this answer,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641751/couldnt-attach-file-send-email-android-11